# Where date difference between now and max date value is greater than X

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, max, datediff

I want to return a result set (from postgres database) containing clients whose last payment date was more than X number of days ago.

This is what I have currently to get a list of all clients and their last payment date:

```
  select usermaster.userid, date_trunc('days', now()-max(paymentdate)) as last_payment
  from usermaster, paymentdetail 
  where usermaster.userid=paymentdetail.userid
  group by usermaster.userid;
```

I would like to limit with an extra where condition: where ... and last_payment > 100 days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

EDIT -

```
select * from 
(SELECT usermaster.userid, date_trunc('days', now()-max(paymentdate)) as  
        last_payment
from usermaster, paymentdetail 
where usermaster.userid=paymentdetail.userid
group by usermaster.userid ) as temptab
where last_payment>100;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I hadn't encountered the HAVING option before. Unfortunately it doesn't work. Postgres gives ERROR:  column "last_payment" does not exist

Comment: Yes, this has worked for me. I was even able to modify it to be an update statement. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add `having` at the end:

```
having trunc('days', now()-max(paymentdate)) > 100
```